# How do Zones work from a Runepriest?

Tags: dnd-4e, zone, runepriest

I've been playing as a Runepriest for a number of sessions now. I have two powers that create Zones, but I think I've been using them wrong and couldn't find any clarification.

Both are similar. They create a zone with certain buffs and said zone can be Sustained from turn to turn with a minor action (Sustain: Minor)

Does the location of the zone change as my character moves, since it does say its Burst 1 or Burst 3 (and that comes from my character)? Or is the zone static once the power is used? OR, does the zone relocate whenever I sustain it with a minor action?

I'm starting to think that I cannot move the zone once placed, but as that would be the least beneficial answer, I figured I should turn to people who should know better then me, so that I can get a clear answer.

Answer (score 5):

**It depends on the power.**

By default, zones cannot be moved. *Some* powers include wording along the lines of, "...and you may move the zone up to X squares," in their sustain lines, and so their zones can be moved each time the power is sustained. But if nothing in the power *says* it moves the zone, then the zone cannot be moved.